# How to divide pasted text from textarea into <p> paragraphs that consist of the same number of characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, paragraph

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/zdCyq/15/)

The JSFiddle that I am using seems to be exactly what I need for my project. However, how would I change this current code to ensure each divided paragraph consists of the same amount of characters and all the paragraphs are the same width?

Any help would much be appreciated, especially an updated JSFiddle would be extremely helpful.

```js
    $(function() {
      $('button').on('click', function() {
        var theText = $('textarea').val();
        var i = 200;
        while (theText.length > 200) {
          console.log('looping');
          while (theText.charAt(i) !== '.') {
            i++;
          }

          console.log(i);
          $("#text_land").append("<p>" + theText.substring(0, i + 1) + "</p>");
          theText = theText.substring(i + 1);
          i = 200;
        }

        $('#text_land').append("<p>" + theText + "</p>");
      })

    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="text_land" style="border:1px solid #ccc; padding:25px; margin-bottom:30px;">xzxz</div>
  <textarea style="widht:95%;"></textarea>
  <button>Go</button>
</div>
```

Comment: In such case the paragraph tags would be inserted in the middle of the sentecne. How do you want to determine amount of paragraphs in which text should be devided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all paragraphs must have the same number of charachters but also the same width, then each character must have the same width, and you have to use a mono-spaced font.

With this code you cut the input text into equal chunks and they display in paragraphs with equal widths.

```
$(function () {
    $('button').on('click', function () {
        var theText = $('textarea').val();
        var numberOfCharacters = 50;

        while (theText.length) {
            $("#text_land").append("<p>" + theText.substring(0, numberOfCharacters - 1) + "</p>");
            theText = theText.substring(numberOfCharacters);
        }

    })

})
```

Of course, this doesn't cut the text on the period character like your fiddle, and it may cut in the middle of words, but you can't have your cookie and eat it too.

If you want to ensure that at least words are not cut in the middle, you could loosen your number-of-character-per-line constraint until you find a space like this..

```
$(function () {
    $('button').on('click', function () {
        var theText = $('textarea').val();
        var numberOfCharacters = 20;

        while (theText.length) {
            while (theText.length > numberOfCharacters && theText.charAt(numberOfCharacters) !== ' ') {
                numberOfCharacters++;   
            }
            $("#text_land").append("<p>" + theText.substring(0, numberOfCharacters) + "</p>");
            theText = theText.substring(numberOfCharacters);
        }

    })

})
```

Comment: With this fiddle, part of the letters in the words seem to be missing when continuing onto the next paragraph. Is it possible, to continue to next paragraph, ensuring the word from the previous paragraph is kept and not divided?

Comment: The same amount of characters? No. Think about that for a second. How would you ever ensure that each line is the same fixed number of characters but still have only complete words. That has nothing to do with programming, it's just impossible. That's what I mean with 'you can't have your cookie and eat it too'.

Comment: In the first example fiddle where a letter from a word was missing, could this be changed to include the word for the paragraph before continuing to the second paragraph etc, by dynamically including the last word in each paragraph?

Comment: That is exactly what the second code does. If you really only care about the widths of the paragraphs, not the number of characters, you can apply "text-align: justify" and use some hacky one-line justify like https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/one-line-justified-text-design/